# Proguard 5.0 used in maven POM does not process the -libraryjars correctly (Microsoft sqljdbc4.jar)

Tags: java, sql-server, maven, proguard

I have a working project and wants to obfuscate my company jar's.
The project is a maven (version 2.2.1) based webservice (JRE 1.6.0.45). It works just fine.

To obfuscate it with proguard, i added the following to my POM file:

```
...
...
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
    <maven.repo>C:\Java\Workspaces\Maven2-local-repository</maven.repo>
    <java.home>C:\Java\Tools\jdk1.6.0_45\jre</java.home>
    <proguard.needed.jars>C:\Java\Workspaces\myApp\ProGuardNeededFiles</proguard.needed.jars>
</properties>

...
...
...
      <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
      <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>  
                <configuration>
                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                <includeDependency>false</includeDependency> 
                <injar>test.war</injar>
                <outjar>test_mini.war</outjar> 
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory> 
                <maxMemory>256m</maxMemory>
                <libs>
                    <!--  Java Runtime -->
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
                    <!--  Dependency of a dependency library -->
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/groovy-all-1.5.3.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/droovy-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/jboss-j2ee-4.0.2.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/log4j-1.2.11.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/log4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.1.Final.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/classmate-1.1.0.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/geronimo-validation_1.0_spec-1.0-CR5.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/dom4j-1.4.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/pull-parser-2.1.10.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/xml-apis-2.0.2.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/jboss-logmanager-1.2.1.GA.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/xsdlib-2013.6.1.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/joda-time-2.5.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/logkit-1.3.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/avalon-framework-api-4.3.1.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/commons-jxpath-1.1.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/commons-codec-1.1.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/orai18n-1.0.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/javax.mail-api-1.5.2.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/relaxngDatatype-1.0.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/javolution-5.4.5.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/groovy-2.2.2.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/sax-2.0.1.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/dom-2.3.0-jaxb-1.0.6.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/janino-2.7.6.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/jaxp-api-1.4.5.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/jdi.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/errai-javax-enterprise-3.0.3.Final.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/xdb.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/ons.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/oraclepki.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/asm.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/orai18n.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlpull-1.1.3.4a_1.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxen-1.1.6_1.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/ow2-cdi-1.0-spec-1.0.13.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/xmlparserv2.jar</lib>   
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/commons-compiler-2.6.1.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${proguard.needed.jars}/javax.interceptor-api-1.2.jar</lib>

                    <!-- Libraries added within the WAR file -->
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/${slf4j.version}/slf4j-api-${slf4j.version}.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/${logback.version}/logback-classic-${logback.version}.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/${logback.version}/logback-core-${logback.version}.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/com/mycompany/application_A-1.0.0.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/com/mycompany/application_B-2.0.0.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.6.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.2-GA/javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/cn/guoyukun/jdbc/oracle-ojdbc6/11.2.0.3.0/oracle-ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/com/microsoft/sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.0/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${maven.repo}/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar</lib>
                </libs>                 
                <options>
                    <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                    <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses</option>  
                    <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers</option>    
                    <option>-keepattributes *Annotation*</option>
                    <option>-keepattributes Signature</option>
                    <option>-keepattributes InnerClasses</option>
                    <option>-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod</option>
                    <option>-keepattributes EnclosingMethod</option>

                    <option>-dontshrink</option> 
                    <option>-dontoptimize</option>
                    <option>-dontnote</option>

                    <option>-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn javax.xml.transform.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn javax.transaction.xa.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn org.dom4j.io.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn org.xml.sax.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn oracle.sql.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn groovy.servlet.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn oracle.i18n.servlet.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn oracle.xdb.servlet.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn oracle.xml.jaxp.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn org.apache.xerces.jaxp.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.**</option>
           <!--          <option>-dontwarn com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.**</option>   -->
                    <option>-dontwarn oracle.jdbc.proxy.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn org.apache.commons.beanutils.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn org.apache.commons.configuration.tree.xpath.**</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn oracle.xdb.XMLType</option>

                    <option>-printseeds</option>
                    <option>-printmap obfuscation.map</option>
                    <option>-printusage deadcode.txt</option>

                    <option>-verbose</option>

                    <option>-keep class !com.mycompany.** { *; }</option>
                    <option>-keep class com.mycompany.utility.log.** { *;} </option>
                    <option>-keep class com.mycompany.listeners.** {*;}</option>
                    <option>-keep class com.mycompany.controller.** {*;}</option>
                    <option>-keep @javax.persistence.* class * {*;}</option>
                    <option>-keep class * implements java.sql.Driver</option>
                </options>
            </configuration>
```

In first i had added a *dontwarn* option for the microsoft classes. It builds successfully but after running it in Tomcat I got errors when I access the database.

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver**

So I removed the *dontwarn* option and found the following information after compiling my project:

```
...
...
[proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Java\Tools\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
...
...
[proguard] Initializing...
[proguard] Warning: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerSQLXML: can't find referenced method 'void setFeature(java.lang.String,boolean)' in program class javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
[proguard] Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
[proguard]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[proguard]          You may need to recompile the code.
[proguard]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
[proguard] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[proguard]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
[proguard]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:222)
[proguard]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:97)
[proguard]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:507)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
...
...
...
```

This is strange since the method *setFeature(java.lang.String,boolean)* is a default in the rt.jar library.

I did got all other errors removed by adding the libraries within the ${proguard.needed.jars} folder. I also did need to set a list of dontwarn settings because of missing methods from the dependency class that where not used by my application (think a flaw in the ProGuard tool).

Does someone had the same problem and figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consult the [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) manual?

[Usage, `-libraryjars`](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#libraryjars): *"The specified library jars should at least contain the class files that are extended by application class files. Library class files that are only called needn't be present, although their presence can improve the results of the optimization step."*

You're not *extending* all the jars you specified in <lib>, are you? Remove the *only called* to reduce the number of sources of possible problems first.

[Usage, `-dontwarn`](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#dontwarn): *"Specifies not to warn about unresolved references and other important problems at all. [...] Ignoring warnings can be dangerous. [...] Only use this option if you know what you're doing!"*.

I'd try to get rid of warnings about unresolved references and *other important problems* some other way before suppressing them generally.

Comment: Yes i did read the manual and tried to build up the parameters in my pom. Indeed I don't extend all these libraries in my code. The only extend that I have in my code is the HTTPServlet. But I use for instance LogBack that I instantiate. If I do that and don't have the LogBack jar in my -libraryjars I get the following error: `[proguard] Warning: ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.EvaluatorTemplate: can't find superclass or interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject
 [proguard] Warning: ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.AsyncAppenderDelegate$_closure1: can't find superclass or interface groovy.lang.Closure`

Comment: Did you look at the [#unresolvedclass section on Proguard's Troubleshoot page](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)? Did this not help?

Answer (score 0):

The database driver is loaded by reflection. ProGuard can't know that, so you need to preserve it explicitly:

```
-keep class * implements java.sql.Driver
```

See the ProGuard manual > Examples > [Processing database drivers](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#database).

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > Problems at run-time > [ClassNotFoundException](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#classnotfoundexception).

The warning about the method  ("... can't find ... in program class ...") suggests that you have a copy of javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory in your *program* code or jars (not just the JDK runtime library jar) and that this copy doesn't contain the method. If you don't disable notes, ProGuard prints our notes about duplicate classes.

ProGuard necessarily checks if the input is consistent before processing it, so it may complain about classes, fields, and methods that turn out to be unused. Processing an inconsistent input can lead to all kinds of surprises, as shown here.